# How to show image on popup on click of that image?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created multiple images in div. if any image is clicked then that image will show in another div.(i have got this).but if i clicked image then it will show in popup.
how to show image in popup on click of that image.

```
<div style="height:65px;border:solid 1px #999;"> <img src="images/startdesign images/img7.png" id="fabric" height="63" width="401"/> </div>
```

Comment: <div style="height:65px;border:solid 1px #999;">

<img src="images/startdesign images/img7.png" id="fabric" height="63" width="401"/>
  </div> i want to show this image in popup.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Bootstrap Example</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js">        </script>
<script language="javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){
   $("#img").on('click',function(){
   var src = $("#img").attr('src');
   $("#modalImg").attr('src',src);

});
});

</script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
   <h2>Modal Example</h2>
   <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
   <img src="http://images.forbes.com/media/lists/companies/google_416x416.jpg" id="img" type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"></a>

   <!-- Modal -->
   <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

  <!-- Modal content-->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;  </button>
      <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
         <img id="modalImg">
      </div>

     </div>

   </div>
  </div>

 </div>

</body>
</html>
```